# Print multiple rows array in php

Tags: php, arrays, rows

I have a query which could return multiple rows.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
    foreach ($data as $row){
       echo $row['...'];
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only prints one row, while i should have 2 rows printed.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: it will print all the rows, are you sure the query doesn't return a single row?

Comment: I have entered the query in PhpMyAdmin it does return 2 rows. But when i print the value's i only get 1 row..

Comment: It looks like it should print duplicates actually...  Like it would print 3 rows if 2 were returned, and then 6 if 3 were returned. (Unless $data is being reset.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're re-using the `$row` variable. Also, the logic is a bit strange: why are you looping through `$data` every time you fetch a new row? Did you mean to do this instead:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

foreach ($data as $row){
   echo $row['...'];
}
```

Comment: plus the reuse of row shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I think he wants to iterate over the columns - thats why the foreach was inside the while loop

Comment: Juhana, thanks.. I have noticed my fault haha.. This did the job! Thanks everybody.(Will accept answer when i can.)

Comment: @RageZ @Michael Right, but on the second pass of the while loop he adds another record on `$data` and does the foreach loop again from the beginning. If there are say 3 results, he'll first display `$data[0]`, then `$data[0]` and `$data[1]`, and again `$data[0]`, `$data[1]` and `$data[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v){
       echo $k ." = " . $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
    foreach ($data as $col){
       echo $col['...'];
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

OR

```
echo '<table>';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($data as $col){
        echo '<td>';
       echo $col['...'];
       echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table'>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you iterate the $data array in side the while loop, I think you want to collect all the rows in the $data, and only when while breaks to iterate it to show the results.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $row;

}
foreach ($data as $row){
       echo $row['...'];
    }
```

Or did I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Do some changes in your code for check no. of results

$result = mysql_query($query);



    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        foreach ($row as $val){
           echo $val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the point of checking how many rows as returned? And why would you only want to enter the loop if it was 1?

Comment: Might be query returning single row.

Comment: That wouldn't matter, the while loop will still enter when 1 row is returned